# Using Zend Lucene Search outside an Zend application

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, yii, lucene

I know, there is an Lucene port in zend to get the lucene features in pure PHP.

Is there a way to use that search-code in an non-zend-application, like other PHP frameworks?

Walking through the web I found some very old howto's, but it was not able to apply those old howto to the current releases of zend framework or zend lucene search.

Comment: There is Yii 2 extension using Zend Search with Lucene https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-search-component-v2 - something like this?

Comment: @Bizley  I know, but this extension is to old, because it required zend files and folders which are not part of the currend zend framework download and (2nd) this extension will only work with active record, which is not available, if you get the data from an REST Api (like in my case).